# phpMyAdmin trigger gui checking age

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, database-trigger, raiserror

I want to check whether age is greater than 18 years before inserting the record to 'employees' table. I'm using phpMyAdmin gui trigger tool. But it gives following error when I type this script in Definition section.

```
BEGIN
    IF (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),NEW.birth_date) < 6570) THEN
        RAISEERROR('Age is less than 18 years!',16,1)
        ROLLBACK
    END IF
END
```

[image: error message]

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: `RAISEERROR` and `ROLLBACK` are a TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server) thing. Are you sure that you are using MySQL ?

Comment: what can I use instead of ROLEBACK and  RAISERROR in mySQL? However without those lines it gives the error

Comment: Because these are not Standard SQL thing. Every RDBMS has its own syntax for Triggers.

Comment: Can you suggest me the correct mySQL code for above purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAISEERROR` and `ROLLBACK` are used in TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server) syntax.

In the case of MySQL, we use [`SIGNAL .. SET MESSAGE_TEXT ..`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) to throw an exception inside the Trigger:

```
BEGIN
    IF (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),NEW.birth_date) < 6570) THEN

      -- Throw Exception
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Age is less than 18 years!';

    END IF;  -- A semicolon (delimiter) is missing here
END
```

> To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means
>   “unhandled user-defined exception.”
>
> The error values that are accessible after SIGNAL executes are the
>   SQLSTATE value raised by the SIGNAL statement and the MESSAGE_TEXT and
>   MYSQL_ERRNO items.