# Mysql create trigger syntax error used DELIMITER $$

Tags: mysql, triggers

i tried to prevent duplicated value on a column by this code but got syntax error:

> if exists ( select * from tbl_baivietsp t ' at line 1

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER key_as_linksp ON tbl_baivietsp
AFTER INSERT
AS
if exists ( select * from tbl_baivietsp t inner join INSERTED i on i.LINK_SP 
LIKE CONCAT('%', t.LINK_SP ,'%'))
begin
  rollback TRANSACTION
  RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);
end
go
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can't really know what the problem is after hours, thanks for your time helping me!

Comment: `rollback TRANSACTION
  RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);` these are not mysql trigger syntax. Are you sure that you are not using SQL server instead ?

Comment: yeah im using MYSQL, please correct me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin trigger gui checking age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423662/phpmyadmin-trigger-gui-checking-age)

Comment: just tried this but seems like theres still problem "if exists ( select * from tbl_baivietsp t ' at line 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a Trigger code in TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server); however you are using MySQL. It is recommended to check the Trigger documentation at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
DELIMITER $$

/* AFTER INSERT comes before the table name on which Trigger is being created */
CREATE TRIGGER key_as_linksp AFTER INSERT ON tbl_baivietsp

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN /* Instead of AS, Trigger block starts with FOR EACH ROW BEGIN */

  IF EXISTS ( select 1 from tbl_baivietsp t 
              inner join INSERTED i 
                on i.LINK_SP LIKE CONCAT('%', t.LINK_SP ,'%')) THEN /* THEN is missing */
      /* Throw Exception */
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate Data';
  END IF; /* we use END IF instead of END to end an IF block */

END $$  /* Trigger block ends with END clause */
DELIMITER ;
```

In the case of MySQL, we use [`SIGNAL .. SET MESSAGE_TEXT ..`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) to throw an exception inside the Trigger.

Comment: work like a charm, thank you so much for your answer and your document